# I need to find y' for y^x=x^y

Tags: calculus

It's really just the "generalized power rule" I don't get. Where $D_x[u(x)^{v(x)}] = u(x)^{v(x)}*D_x[ln(u(x))*v(x)]$. Could someone direct me to a proof of that rule?

Comment: If $f(x)=u(x)^{v(x)}$ then $\ln f(x)=v(x)\ln u(x)$.  Now just differentiate both sides.

Answer (score 1):

$$ x^y=y^x$$
Take log both sides and seggregate $x,y$ terms

$$ \frac{y}{\log y }= \frac{x}{\log x} $$

Differentiate and simplify

$$ \frac{dy}{dx}  \frac{(\log y -1)}{(\log y)^2 }= \frac{(\ log\, x -1)}{(\log \,x)^2 }$$

$$ \frac{dy}{dx}  =  \log\,_{(y/e)} {(x/e)}\,\cdot {  (\log _x{y})}^2$$

Comment: I thought this was the question at first as well, but upon further inspection, it does not appear to be what is asked.

Comment: And personally, I'd flip the fractions so that we don't have $\log^2 y$ in the denominator.  Also, are you sure you meant to "seggregate" $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Yes,we can massage the logs more.

Answer (score 1):

$$y=u^v$$

Take the $\ln$ of both sides to get

$$\ln y=v\ln u$$

Differentiate both sides to get

$$\frac{\frac{dy}{dx}}y=\frac d{dx}v\ln u$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=y\left[\frac d{dx}v\ln u\right]=u^v\left[\frac d{dx}v\ln u\right]$$

Answer (score 1):

Solve $y^x=x^y$ for $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

\begin{eqnarray}
e^{x\ln y}-e^{y\ln x}&=&0\\
\left(\ln y+\frac{xy^\prime}{y}\right)y^x-\left(y^\prime\ln x+\frac{y}{x}\right)x^y&=&0\\
y^x\ln y+xy^\prime y^{x-1}-y^\prime x^y\ln x-yx^{y-1}&=&0\\
\left(xy^{x-1}-x^y\ln x\right)y^\prime&=&yx^{y-1}-y^x\ln y\\
\frac{dy}{dx}&=&\dfrac{yx^{y-1}-y^x\ln y}{xy^{x-1}-x^y\ln x}
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 0):

May be, you could consider the implicit function $$F=y^x-x^y=0$$ and use the implicit function theorem $$F'_x=y^x \log (y)-y x^{y-1}\qquad F'_y=x y^{x-1}-x^y \log (x)$$ $$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{F'_x}{F'_y}=\frac{y x^{y-1}-y^x \log (y)}{x y^{x-1}-x^y \log (x)}$$ Another solution could involve Lambert function since $$y^x=x^y\implies y=-\frac{x }{\log (x)}W\left(-\frac{\log (x)}{x}\right)$$ from which $$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{(\log (x)-1)\, W\left(-\frac{\log (x)}{x}\right)^2}{\log ^2(x)
   \left(1+W\left(-\frac{\log (x)}{x}\right)\right)}$$